# Difference between a connection failed or no response in an https connection in iPhone

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection, xcode6.3, nsurlerrordomain

We have used NSURLConnection for establishing the connection with the server.
Can we differentiate between a connection failed or no response received from the server in an https connection in iOS 8(Xcode 6.3)?
If yes, then please help us with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSURLConnectionDelegate` method `-connection:didFailWithError:` provides you with error describing reason for failure. You can differentiate between situations based on `error.code` - list of codes [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes).

Comment: Thanks Jakub for your quick response. Do I need to handle each error code individually?

Comment: Only the ones you need to handle in other than default way.. Also - errors have `localizedDescription` property, which can be used for displaying problem to the user..